# MySQL How to substract two DATETIME and INT value

Tags: mysql

I store "start_time", "finish_time" and "meal" time as

```
start_time = DATETIME
finish_time = DATETIME
meal = INT - store minitues
```

Now I want to **get deference between start_time , finish_time after that i want to subtract meal time form hours** how to do that,

```
eg:
start_time             finish_time           meal
2014-10-24 08:30:00    2014-10-24 18:30:00   45
```

output should be: **9:15**

How to get that using MySQL only,

**I have try to use TIMESTAMPDIFF but I don't know how to subtract meal and convert it to H:m format :**

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time, finish_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do ordinary subtraction:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time, finish_time) - meal
```

To convert this to `H:m` format, divide it by 60 and get the modulus from 60:

```
CONCAT(FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time, finish_time) - meal)/60),
      ':', 
      (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time, finish_time) - meal) % 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time, finish_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        (
            (
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`finish_time`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_time`) /* difference in seconds */
            ) / 60 - `meal` /* transform in minutes, substract minutes */
        ) * 60 /* seconds again */
    ) AS `timediff` /* to time :) */
FROM `table`
```